# How to iterate rows <tr> with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to create a collapsible table. If you click on a row, its sub-rows must appear, as you see in this pic

[image]

For now I just want to show all rows and sub-rows, and I'm having problem doing it.

A single row Object is something like this:

```
{
cells: ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
childRows: [{
            cells: ["child cell1", "child cell2", "child cell3"],
            childRows: []
            }]
}
```

I created a component for the `<tr>`, since it has some special code (that I don't show here to avoid bothering you with all my code).

I used an "attribute" style selector for my `<tr>` component, since I can't append a tag inside the `<table>` tag, otherwise W3C validator fails the check.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-table-row]',
})
```

I added the component selector to the `<tbody>` of the table:

```
<tbody app-table-row [table]="table" [rows]="table.rows">
```

This is my component template, and this is how I tried to call it **recursively**:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <tr >
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row.cells">
      {{cell}}
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!--here is the error
  If current row has sub-rows I have to show sub-rows-->
  <ng-container *ngIf="row.childRows" app-table-row [table]="table" [rows]="row.childRows"></ng-container><

</ng-container >
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
```

I suppose because I'm trying to append a `<tr>` to a `ng-container`. I tried other codes but I'm still stuck!

Comment: Try to use Material collapsible table. (Table with expandable rows)
 https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples  . If this is not what you are looking for, drop a comment.

Comment: Hi @Anglesvar, unfortunately I have to edit the table component of my app. I can't use or import other component

Comment: Can you add sample data? Let me check!.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-container` exists to solve the problem of situations where you need to use more than one structural directive on an element, which you can't do without using ng-container as a wrapper to host one of those directives. It's not a drop-in replacement for a `<div>`, etc, so your intuition of not being able to append to it is correct since it's not a "real" element.

If you can't use a component library like Material for this, there are several ways to get this done. Is there a reason that you can't use CSS to hide the rows, triggered by a click handler on the `<tr>`? Barring that, the suggestion to use Material for this is a good one.

Comment: My problem is not to hide or show the sub-rows; I'm having problem "adding them" to the DOM using a *ngFor. I have to loop my rows array, and If a row has a subrow I have to add to the DOM the sub-rows